# Why won't declaring an array final make it immutable in Java?

Tags: java, immutability, final

Why won't declaring an array final make it immutable in Java? Doesn't declaring something final mean it can't be changed?

From [question related to immutable array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700971/immutable-array-in-java) it's clear that declaring an array final doesn't make it unchangeable.

The following is possible.

```
final int[] array = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3};
array[0] = 42;
```

My question is: What is the function of declaring final here then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339930/final-array-in-java

Comment: While many answers talk about references [to objects], I like to simply say that `final` is *only* an attribute of the *variable/field* and has nothing to do with the *object/value* that variable/field evaluates to. Variables/fields and objects/values are different things. Only the former are affected by the modifier.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`final` is only about the *reference* that is marked by it; there is no such thing as an immutable array in Java. When you say

```
private final int[] xs = new int[20];
```

you won't be allowed to say

```
xs = new int[10];
```

later on. That's all what `final` is about. More generally, ensuring that an object is immutable is often hard work and full of a range of subtleties. The language itself doesn't give much to this end out of the box.

Comment: However, there are immutable collections. ([`Collections.emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) and [`Collections.unmodifiableList(List<? extends T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) for instance)

Comment: @Powerlord `Collections.emptyList()` is a better example; `Collections.unmodifiableList()` is just a wrapper and the underlying list can still be changed anytime.

Comment: `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` isn't Generic, which is why `.emptyList()` exists.

Comment: @Powerlord - but that is beside the point ... which is immutablility, and how it is implemented in Java.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, you _can_ create an immutable array in Java. `new int[0]`. :)

Comment: One potential difference here is that, IIRC, the final modifier *DOES* have semantics with regard to the Java Memory Model. Consider if the type of array was not `int`, but was some object type, `final` would guarantee that all array elements would be fully initialised before any other thread sees a reference to them. I don't have JCIP to hand to confirm, unfortunately.

Comment: @Grundlefleck Don't need JCIP, you can get it [from the horse's mouth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5). Of course, those semantics are only valid if you don't leak that field or `this` from the constructor, and if you ever modify the array (including modifying one of its object, if it's an array of reference types) after the constructor returns, all bets are off.

Answer (score 8):

`final` means you can't change the *reference* - ie you can't assign another array to that field.

"Immutable" means you can't change the *contents* of the array - `final` has no effect on that.

As your code shows, you can assign a value to *one of the elements* of the array, which doesn't change the *reference to* the array

Answer (score 3):

Here you are making a *object reference* `final`, not a primitive. (Arrays are special Java objects, too.)
Making a reference `final` means that you cannot make it refer something else once it is initialized. But of course you can change the state of an object referred by a final variable.

Answer (score 1):

> declaring an array

In Java, we declare *variables*, and create *objects* (such as arrays). These actions are independent; we can declare a variable without creating an object, and create an object without declaring a variable.

Immutability is a property of an object, while final is a property of a variable. An object may be referred to by several variables. Which variable should govern immutability of the array object?

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
final int[] b = a;
a[0] = 10; // should this be legal?
```

If we permit this, the supposedly immutable value of `b[0]` has been changed. But how can the compiler prevent this? By making it impossible to assign a non-final to a final reference? How would I initialize the array, then? I couldn't do so in a loop ...

And: What does it even mean for an array to be immutable? For instance, should the following compile?

```
final int[][] a = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
a[1][1] = 5;
```

C++ solves this by permitting `const` to be specified (or omitted) for each level of indirection. In Java, final can be specified (or omitted) once per variable. Yes, `final` is a simpler `const`, much like Java is a simpler C++. Let's keep it simple, shall we?

Comment: I consider the inability to specify attributes at different levels of indirection to be a major limitation of Java, since there is a fundamental difference between an `int[]` which encapsulates a sequence of numbers as a non-sharable reference to an array the owner may change, an `int[]` which encapsulates a sequence of numbers as a sharable reference to an array which all holders agree never to change, and an `int[]` which *identifies* an array owned by some other entity.  One wouldn't need to worry about "deep" versus "shallow" cloning or equality if the type system made such distinctions.

Comment: With regard to your example, the Java array declaration syntax makes it unclear how to apply attributes to layers.  If declarations were more of a generic style: `final ImmutableArray<ImmutableArray<int>> a = {...}` things would be much clearer.  An `ImmutableArray<T>` or an `Array<T>` could be implicitly converted to a `ReadableArray<T>`, though not vice versa.  Code which held a `ReadableArray<T>` reference could try to cast it to a `MutableArray<T>`, succeeding at run-time only if the type was actually mutable.

Comment: @supercat: If you feel this strongly about this, you're free to create an ImmutableArray wrapper class around an array that enforces the semantics you want. Or you might use [`ImmutableList`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html). I therefore disagree that a lack of const for array types is a major limitation of java. At most, it is a limitation of Java *arrays* with an easy workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It means that a new instance of the object would not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone commented, declaring it final will not let you assign another array to your variable. Read more [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html)

The array itself will retain it's properties same as before.