# Delete file from a file list

Tags: java, android, string, file, list

I am creating an android application, and I created a list of available files in the internal memory with this instruction:

```
final String[] files =fileList();
```

I need to remove a file from this list and I don't know how, can you help me?

Comment: You have declared the array as final, final variables cannot be changed.

Comment: JNL, to be clear, the value 'files' can not be reassigned, but the values (if there are any) in the array can change.  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10339930/42962

Answer (score 4):

To "*remove*" something you can just set it back to null, or you can do it the hard way with a loop that shifts everything behind it up a place.

```
public void remove( int index ) { 
    for(int i=index; i<sarr.length()-1; i++) { 
        sarr[i] = sarr[i+1] 
    } 
    sarr[sarr.length()-1] = null; 
    System.out.println("Removed!"); 
}
```

When using primitive arrays like this, there is no removal method. If you built a more complex datatype you could have the "remove" method available to you.

Comment: Agreed, you'd be better off using, for example, `ArrayList<String>`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `List<String>` instead. That way you can remove the file that you want using the `remove()` method.

```
index = 0//location of item to be removed, with the first item in the list at 0
List<String> files = Arrays.asList(getFiles());
files.remove(index)
```

in this example, index is the location of the item that you want to remove. Alternatively, you could do this instead

```
item = "fileLocation";
List<String> files = Arrays.asList(getFiles());
files.remove(item)
```