# Final String[] and Final String

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, actionlistener, final

I am confused. I tried using

```
final String usr;
```

and trying to change its value never worked, but when I used an array `final String[] usr = {"", ""};`, it worked. I even accessed it from this

```
sgnup.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         user[0] = sUsr.getText();
      }
 });
```

I find it very confusing because my understanding of `final` is that a variable declared with `final` and add a value to it, the value never changes. But why did an array with `final` work? I can even set a text to one of those arrays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works

Comment: Arrays are never immutable in Java.

Comment: I guess your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339930/final-array-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you don't change the reference of `usr` but what it contains. `final` block you from doing something like `usr = new String[5];` (change the `usr` to another array) but the content of the array can be changed without problems.

```
final String[] a = new String[5];
a = new String[3]; // illegal

final String[] a = new String[5];
a[0] = "Hello"; // legal, i don't change a but what is inside a[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a variable of any object type (including any array) actually is a *reference* to an object, not the object itself. When you declare a variable to be `final`, it means that the reference will not change, meaning that the object it references will always be the same object. However, if the internal state of the object can still change without the `final` modifier, then adding `final` won't prevent the internal state of the referenced object from changing. In particular for a `final` array, the array reference itself cannot be reassigned, but the array elements can still change.

In your situation, you can avoid using an array by simply eliminate the `final` modifier from the `String` variable.