# final int in Java

Tags: java, arrays, final

I have a relatively simple question regarding the function of `final` in Java.
When I compile this code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Arrays
{
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
 {
final int[] myArray = { 1,2 }; 
myArray[1] = 3; 
System.out.println (myArray[1]);  
 }
}
```

The number "3" gets printed. However, I was under the impression that `final` meant that the values held in that array (myArray) can no longer change and are constant.

There is also another piece of code here:

```
final int [] a1 = {1, 2}; 
int [] b1 = {3, 4};
a1 = b1; System.out.println (a1[1]);
```

I believe that the system should print "2" since `a1` is finalized and the values in the array are constant. However, my friend believes that it should be "4". Please help me clear up my understanding of `final`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I edit the contents of a final array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339930/why-can-i-edit-the-contents-of-a-final-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

An `int[]` is an object type (not a primitive and not an `int`). The final reference means you can't reassign the reference when referring to an `Object` instance.

```
final int [] a1 = {1, 2}; 
a1 = {3,4}; // <-- illegal, a1 is final.
```

In fact, Java is making the *value* `final` in both cases (the value of an `Object` is its' reference).

Comment: You're saying an array of primitives is an `Object`?

Comment: @mrres1 Every array is an `Object`.

Comment: @mrres1 [JLS-10.1. Array Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1) says (in part) *The direct superclass of an array type is `Object`.* And your linked answer is talking about C++ (not Java).

Answer (score 0):

Final means a value cannot be changed.
But when `int[] myArray;` is declared then myArray holds the reference of the array and not the values.
So the statement,
myArray[1] = 3;
changes the contents at that position because it is not declared as final.
and the statement `myArray = (any value);` is illegal since we are changing the reference which is declared as final.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a variable as final you cannot reassign it to another value.

```
final int a = 2;
a = 5; \\ error
```

similarly, when you use a final array:

```
final int[] arrA = {1,2,3};
arrA = new int[]{4, 5, 6}; \\ error
```

But you can always change the values inside the array, as they are not `final`. Therefore it seems like your second example will not compile. If you do not want to change the values inside an array then you are better off with `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

A `final` modifier declares the variable cannot change. However, object/array variables are really just handles to unnamed objects/arrays. Since the value of a object variable is a handle, it ensures the *handle* cannot change. The array on the other end of that handle has nothing to do with `final` at all.

```
 final int myInt = 5; //myInt cannot change (5 is the value of myInt)
 final int[] myArr = {1,2};
 myArr[0] = 3; //legal. myArr is a handle to a int[] and we're not modifying the handle
```